# Without localstorage how we can store the value

Tags: angular, reactjs, redux

Without local storage, I want to store my value. because the value can be visible in the developer tool for local storage. There is a way to store a value in storage that can't be seen in the developer tool. Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: Yep, using server side caching or storing

Comment: Can you give us more details? What type of value? What if you encrypt the value and the user can't read the value?

Comment: You can still store in the localstorage, but encrypt value before putting it there. Will be much harder to decrypt especially with obfuscated JS code in production. However, it's still way better to store all sensitive data on the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **JWT** encode to encode the data in API and set it to local storage, from angular you can use `this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(responsedata)` to decode the data,using this technique you can hide the data visibility in local storage, you can also use cookie to store the data

**install ngx-cookie-service from npm**

create a object for cookie service

```
private cookieService: CookieService
```

**Set data**

```
this.cookieService.set( 'Test', 'Hello World' )
```

Comment: but these item got deleted with refresh. or closing tab.

Answer (score 1):

> RxJS powered state management for Angular applications, inspired by Redux.
>   @ngrx/store is a controlled state container designed to help write performant, consistent applications on top of Angular.

Better to follow given link for more information.
[ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store)

[Here](https://mherman.org/blog/authentication-in-angular-with-ngrx/) is a good blog to go through to learn further.